# Flutter Serverpod. i can't start the server

Tags: flutter, dart

> i got the error message ***The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14*** after executing the command below in the server package:

```
dart bin/main.dart
```

````
*bin/main.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
import 'package:uzaapp_server/server.dart';
^
lib/server.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
import 'package:serverpod/serverpod.dart';
^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod-0.9.20/lib/serverpod.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
library serverpod;
^
lib/src/web/routes/root.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
import 'dart:io';
^
lib/src/generated/protocol.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED CODE DO NOT MODIFY */
^
lib/src/generated/endpoints.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED CODE DO NOT MODIFY */
^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod-0.9.20/lib/server.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
library server;
^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod-0.9.20/lib/relic.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
export 'src/relic/web_server.dart';
^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod-0.9.20/lib/database.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
library database;
^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod_serialization-0.9.20/lib/serverpod_serialization.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.14.
library serverpod_serialization;
^*

i am on :
Dart 2.18.4
Flutter 3.3.8
serverpod 0.9.20

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'
```
````

Answer (score 0):

you need to downgrade your dart version to lower then 2.14

here are the docs for a downgrade
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-downgrade